# How can I see what processes are running on a remote ubuntu server and kill them?

Tags: ssh, nohup

I started some processes with nohup and they aren't working correctly so I need to find and kill them but I dont know the pid or anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SSH in and then use the ps command to list running processes in conjunction with the grep command to filter that result list down to what you need:

```
ps aux | grep something
```

"ps aux" returns a list of all processes currently running
"grep something" takes that list (via the pipe ("|")) and just outputs strings that match "something".

So for example if you wanted to find the httpd process you could use

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

The results will contain the PID you can use to kill them.

Answer (score 4):

No need for any pipes with pgrep:

```
pgrep -l httpd
```